# To start in or at a company?

Tags: prepositions

I am not sure about what is right:

> I can start my career at an international company.

or

> I can start my career in an international company.

For me at sounds appropriate?

Comment: Either is fine, although I'd favor *in* because of your use of *company*.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use either but I like *at* to describe your linkage with a company overall.  If you are being more specific about what part of a company I feel that *in* flows better.

> Usage:
>
> I can start at IBM in March.
>
> I can start in the Engineering Department in March.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can understand what is meant when someone says "work in the company," it sounds odd to me.  So, I tried to see how many instances of it I might be able to find through collocation databases, Google's Ngram or even just a general search of the web, and was quite surprised to see that "in the company" is much more prevalent that "at the company."  Below is what I found via the web:

[image]

However, I should point out that a search of "in the company" doesn't rule out such set phrases as "in the company of" (which would sound really strange if one were to say instead "at the company of").  Likewise, "I work in a company with 250 people" sounds perfectly natural, and the two other prepositions I've mentioned — for and at — would be completely interchangeable in a sentence like this.

At the moment, all I have as a basis of authority on this matter is the fact that I am a native speaker of American English and "work in the company" sounds odd to me.  In fact, the word "in" draws to my mind, perhaps to some degree automatically or subconsciously, some sort of physicality, whereas the preposition "at" much less so.  Because I would understand what someone meant if they chose to say, "I work in the company," I likely wouldn't wonder if they meant "in(side)" the company (as opposed to outside of it), but I wouldn't think the person was a native speaker of English (not American English anyway), and, depending on my mood or the situation, I might even try to make some sort of joke out of it (not to make the person feel bad, but to use it as a teaching moment of some sort and/or attempt to build rapport).

I am not the only one who feels this way about it.  Just do a search of the web and you'll find others who agree with me on this.  (I'd provide specific links here, but the web is acting really crazy right now and I am having difficulty connecting to much of anything at the moment.)  If it helps, WordReference is usually a good place to start.

Personally, I prefer "work for the company," but from some other discussion threads I found, I realized that such a phrase can be somewhat ambiguous.  It can mean you work directly for the company.  It can mean you work for the company as a contractor and your real employer is actually some entity other than the company itself.  And it can also mean you are a freelancer who is doing some work for a particular company.

Another monkey in this wrench is the fact that actually specifying the name of the company may be a game changer if this next image of usage is any indicator:

[image]