# Doing something in/at the company, which one is correct?

Tags: prepositions

Would you say?

> I won employee of the month in my company.

or

> I won employee of the month at my company.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To start in or at a company?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169531/to-start-in-or-at-a-company)

Comment: Not answering the question but I think "employee of the month" should be capitalized or put in quotes or something, to indicate more clearly that it is a specific title or award. (I slightly favour "at" but it's only personal preference, as KillingTime's link proves.)

Comment: *I won employee of the month in my company.* "in/at my company" is not required: you are unlikely to have won the award from another company...  but, if you insist, idiomatically: *"I won my company's "Employee of the month" award."*

Comment: hmm not really....I get it when you start a job at a company because you're going to be around the premise of the company, my question is slightly different to the one you linked

Comment: @Jason If the duplicate doesn't answer the question, please edit yours to explain why it doesn't. Thanks.